# How to implement Navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create an app. I am not getting  Hamburger Button  only back arrow is showing on action bar. How to show Hamburger button show on action bar. Using the following code-

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
DrawerLayout mDrawer;
TextView messageTextView;
ListView mDrawerListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get references to the TextView and DrawerLayout
    messageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // These lines are needed to display the top-left hamburger button
    mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Make the hamburger button work
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawer,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        }
    };



    // Change the TextView message when ListView item is clicked
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           messageTextView.setText("Menu Item at position " + position + " clicked.");;
           mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
       }
    });
}

   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }


    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

How to show  Hamburger Button on action bar.I am getting only back arrow on action bar please tell me how to display Hamburger Button on action bar.

Thanks

[error description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI7k8.png)

Comment: drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawer,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        }
    };
```

To,

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

            }
        };
```

**NOTE :** You need to keep Icon in drawable folder. or you can use system's default one.

Happy coding.

Comment: i added first already "R.drawable.ic_drawer" that time I click on  Hamburger Button menu is open but the Hamburger didn't change to back arrow..I want when i click on Hamburger button then change in to back arrow

Comment: @vrund First, that's not a valid constructor for either version of `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. Second, only the v4 version takes a drawable Resource ID, and that version doesn't have the hamburger-arrow animation.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your actionBarDrawerToggle in this way : This should work

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                toggle.syncState();

            }


        };
```

Comment: This Source code  getting error ..crash problem when start the app

Comment: can you check now ?  if there is still error please paste the logcat

Comment: i posted log cat to see error please click on  "error description here"